# Closing an active mdi child

Tags: c#

I have this code where i can close and open a child form using a menu strip. My question is how do i close a specific active child form if i have multiple child forms that is active?

```
private void fileMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmtview tv = new frmtview();
    if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
    {
        ActiveMdiChild.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        tv.MdiParent = this;
        tv.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        tv.Show();
    }

}


private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmtview tv = new frmtview();
    tv.MdiParent = this;
    tv.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
    tv.Show();

}
```

Comment: do you want to close active mdi child form or want to close specific child form which may be not active?

Comment: i want to close a specific child form

Comment: to close the form you must have at least an object of that form or form name. if you have form name then you can close that form by calling Application.OpenForms["formName"].Close();

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean all opened child windows? If so, when open/create child window, add the object to the list<>(member variable). when click over the close menu, just iterate all items in the list and call close method.

List childControls = new List();

```
void Closeclick(.......)
{
   foreach(UserControl uc in childControls)
   {
      uc.Close();
   }
}

void ActivateClick(.......)
{
    HomeForm home = new HomeForm();
    childControls.Add(home);
    home.Show();    
}
```